# Convert String Numerical Operation to actual Integer Operation

Tags: c++, string

A user inputs a string in the form `num1*num2` an is stored in string `s`.

How do i use `stoi` to convert num1 and num 2 to actual integers numbers and return the product?

Say the user inputs: `56*2`, how would i grab 56 and 2 from that, since both `num1` and `num2` can be as big or as small as the user inputs them to be. I was told this could be done in 2 lines of code using `stoi` (the conversion and operation).

Comment: for a simple case with only 1 operator like this you can just split the string, otherwise you need a parser/expression calculator

Answer (score 0):

Use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) and convert the string into integer:

```
string num1, num2;
getline(cin, num1, '*');
getline(cin, num2);
return (stoi(num1) * stoi(num2));
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2n7WHi)